# SQL query to list rows in one line

Tags: sql, ms-access

Below displays the value for table called "PRIZE"

```
PRIZE

event_code  place  prizemoney
0101        1      $120
0101        2      $60
0101        3      $30
0102        1      $10
0102        2      $5
0103        1      $100
0103        2      $60
0103        3      $40
0201        1      $10
0201        2      $5
0401        1      $1000
0401        2      $500
0401        3      $250
0501        1      $10
0501        2      $5
```

Now the question is:

**For each event with at least three prizes, list the event_id and the prize money available for first, second and third prize on one line.  Order the table by event_id.  The results will appear as follows, although your attribute names may be different:**

```
event_Id   first    second   third
101        120       60       30
```

This is how I approached the solution

```
SELECT A.event_id, B.place, C.place, D.place
FROM PRIZE AS A, PRIZE AS B, PRIZE AS C, PRIZE AS D
WHERE A.event_id = B.event_id
AND A.event_id = C.event_id
AND A.event_id = D.event_id;
```

I tried using SELF (Recursive) JOIN but it is still showing error.

How would the SQL query look like for this question?

Comment: Proposed an answer. Please mark it accepted, if it's correct. Upvote it, if it helped you. If something is wrong, please feel free to post a comment.

Comment: Just for the record, what was the error text you got in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
SELECT p.event_id,  
       (SELECT prizemoney  
        FROM prize first  
        WHERE first.place = 1  
        AND   first.event_id = p.event_id) AS "first",  
       (SELECT prizemoney  
        FROM prize second  
        WHERE second.place = 2  
        AND   second.event_id = p.event_id) AS "second",  
       (SELECT prizemoney  
        FROM prize third  
        WHERE third.place = 3  
        AND   third.event_id = p.event_id) AS "third",  
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT event_id FROM prize) p  
ORDER BY p.event_id;
```

**Data constraint using index**

You may consider a UNIQUE index on `(event_id, place)`, if you don't have one already. This will prevent multiple rows with the same `(event_id, place)` combination but a different `prizemoney`, which would answer the quetsion "What's the prize money for first winner on event 5? I don't know, could be 10 or 100, because there are two rows...".

**Query performance**

If you want your DBMS not to read a DB-page for each `prizemoney` in the sub-select, then you can have another UNIQUE index on `(event_id, place, prizemoney)`, such that the DBMS can read the prizemoney using a "INDEX ONLY SCAN". You'll need both indices - the first to constrain your requirements, the second for a `prizemoney` lookup with index access without table access. The second index on the three columns will duplicate all data in the table and could be a waste of space. Try it without this index first. If performance requires it, add the all columns index.

Comment: your code has worked and it is giving the exact result what the question wanted. really appreciate it :)

Comment: I just have one question though. You have used p.event_id. What is the role or purpose of p ? ... I will really appreciate it if you can clarify it :)

Comment: @stranger It gives the name `p` to the virtual result of the `SELECT DISTINCT` table in the `FROM` clause of the main query. You sometimes need names. For example, to disambiguate a SELF-JOIN of the same table t with names t1 and t2 to `JOIN ON t1.id = t2.id`. In the query above, two `event_id` columns, which are from the virtual table of the sub-query named p on the one hand, and from `first`, `second`, `third` on the other hand (respectively). Please accept the answer, if it is correct. Please upvote, if the answer, this comment helped you. You will get points for accept, 2! It's important!

Comment: In other words, how do you differentiate between two equal things? Name different things differently. If you have two apples, you can name them differently to distinguish them. How many tables are named in the `FROM` clauses? Are you referring to the same table multiple times? (Yes, see `FROM prize`). `prize p` makes p an alias to the (table) result of the query to the outer part of the query. If you have named the virtual result table of the inner query to `p`, then you (usually) need to refer columns of this virtual table by both name and column `p.some_column_here`, like `p.event_id`.

Comment: @stranger You may want to mark the answer correct and upvote it, too - when appropriate. You will get points, by which others will recognize that you are a knowing new member of StackOverflow... Do unaccepted correct answers negatively affect the chances to get help from other members of the community?